# $g_n = m(E_n)^{\frac{-1}{q}}\chi_{E_n}$. Show $\int fg_n \rightarrow 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$. Let $E_n$ be measurable sets of finite measure, where $\lim_{n \to \infty}m(E_n)=0$. Let $p,q$ be such that $1<p,q<\infty$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$. And define $g_n = m(E_n)^{\frac{-1}{q}}\chi_{E_n}$. Show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f g_n = 0$.

I can't figure out how to get this one off the ground. I initially thought to use Holder's inequality and then take the limit of $||f||_p||g_n||_q$, but $||g_n||_q = 1$, so that's not getting me anywhere.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hölder gives you $\Vert f \chi_{E_n}\Vert_p \cdot \Vert g_n \Vert_q$, which will allow you to conclude what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Hölder gives you
$$\left\vert \int fg_n \right\vert 
\leq  \int \vert fg_n \vert 
\leq \Vert f \chi_{E_n}\Vert_p \cdot \Vert g_n \Vert_q = \Vert f \chi_{E_n}\Vert_p,$$
which will allow you to conclude what you want.

Comment: I thought I understood your argument at first, but now I'm not sure I do.

The $\chi_{E_n}$ is part of the definition of $g_n$, and in fact if I move it over to $f$, then I no longer have $||g_n||_q = 1$. From the definition of $g_n$ we have $\int |g_n|^q = \int |m(E_n)^\frac{-1}{q}\chi_{E_n}|^q = \int |\frac{1}{m(E_n)} \chi_{E_n}^q|= \frac{1}{m(E_n)}\int \chi_{E_n}^q = \frac{m(E_n)}{m(E_n)} = 1$. If I were to move $\chi{E_n}$ over to $f$, then the integral just becomes $\frac{1}{m(E_n)}$, which will approach $\infty$

Comment: The point is that $\chi_{E_n}= \chi_{E_n} \cdot \chi_{E_n}$, thus you can move it to both sides. Is it clear? Otherwise I can elaborate on that point (or other things that are not clear to you)

Comment: Ahh. I hadn't thought about using the idempotency of $\chi_{E_n}$. Okay. This is much more clear. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Great :) Glad I could help